# issue with div on IE when scrolling and dragging enabled

Tags: html, jquery-draggable

I have div with dragging and scrolling enabled. Before enabling the dragging the scrolling works properly as i make the div draggable the scrolling give some weird behavior.When i click on scroll bar it seems like scrolling event doesn't finish and the div keep dragging around.Problem only on IE browser.

```
     function test() {
     $('#dvDrag').draggable({
         start: function (event, ui) { },
         stop: function (event, ui) { }

     });
 }

<input  type="button" onclick="test()"/>
<div id="dvDrag" style="width:100px; height:150px; overflow:scroll">
    test drag<br />
    test drag<br />
    test drag<br />
    test drag<br />
    test drag<br />
    test drag<br />
    test drag<br />
    test drag<br />
    test drag<br />
    test drag<br />
    </div>
```

Comment: Did anyone ever came across such issue? I need this ASAP.